# Compare two list with map

Tags: elixir

I have 2 list with map

```
products= [
  %{
    "id" => "7",
    "use_count" => 1,
    "name" => "A",
    "price" => "$1",
    "base_count" => 2
  },
  %{
    "id" => "8",
    "use_count" => 0,
    "name" => "B",
    "price" => "$14",
    "base_count" => 0
  },
  %{
    "id" => "9",
    "use_count" => 1,
    "name" => "C",
    "price" => "$29",
    "base_count" => 0
  }
]
```

and

```
margin=[
  %{name: "aa", id: 9, base_count: 1},
  %{name: "bb", id: 7, base_count: 1}
]
```

I want to compare 2 list based on `id`. If for any `base_count` in `products` is less than `base_count` of `margin` , then I want throw the error as

```
        {:error, "product count cant be less than margin count"}
```

Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is extremely ill-formed, in `products` `id`s are strings, in `margins` they are integers, what does mean “throw an error” is unclear.

As it is stated, the problem might be approached this way:

```rb
lookup = fn id ->
  (Enum.find(margin, &match?(%{id: ^id}, &1)) || %{base_count: 0}).base_count
end

result =
  Enum.reduce(products, %{}, fn %{"id" => id, "base_count" => base_count}, acc ->
    id = String.to_integer(id)
    diff = lookup.(id) - base_count
    if diff > 0,
      do: Map.put(acc, id, diff),
      else: acc
  end)
```

Now one might check if `result` is not empty and “throw” the error, whatever it means.

---

*Sidenote:* I would start with normalizing `id`s and maybe grouping `margins` by `id` to make lookups more efficient, but this I would leave for the homework.

Answer (score 0):

A typical problem that can be solved by **hashtable** (or **map** (the datatype) in Elixir).

1. Index your products by `id`

```
products_by_id = products
                 |> Stream.map(fn product -> {String.to_integer(product["id"]), product} end)
                 |> Enum.into(%{})
```

2. Check if there's a margin whose `base_count` is greater than the corresponding product's `base_count`.

```
if Enum.any?(margin, fn m -> m[:base_count] > products_by_id[m[:id]]["base_count"] end) do
  {:error, "product count cant be less than margin count"}
end
```

As Aleksei Matiushkin said, consistency of data types is very important. It helps you write less code and avoid many bugs. So you really should fix your data first if you can.

Comment: `Stream.map/2` in the first snippet makes a little sense here (but it slows down the process.) `Enum.into(products, %{}, &{String.to_integer(&1["id"]), &1})`. But as I stated in my answer, we have [`Enum.group_by/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html?#group_by/3) for that out of the box.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin The values given by the `Enum.group_by` are lists which could be a little difficult to handle. I wish Elixir has an `Enum.index_by/2`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider products and margins ids are the same type

```
margin_base_count = Enum.into(margin, %{}, &{&1.id, &1.base_count})

Enum.reduce_while(products, :ok, fn %{"id" => id, "base_count" => base_count}, _acc ->
  case base_count < margin_base_count[id]  do
    true -> {:halt, {:error, "product count cant be less than margin count"}}
    false -> {:cont, :ok}
  end
end)
```